# Created a table with 4 columns and 3 rows. How do I set up a php script to pull each row by id to generate 3 tr from the dababase?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

The table I am looking to pull from my database is com/bzkItsK.  It currently pulls the first row in the database but I am unsure about how to set up a script that will pull all the rows (currently 4) by their id to the webpage.

Here is the html as I have set it:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>user id</th>
           <th>First Name</th>
           <th>Last Name</th>
           <th>Department</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php echo $rows[$user_id];?></th>
            <td><?php echo $rows[$first_name];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows[$last_name];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows[$dept];?></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

mysql_query is as such.

mysql_connect("localhost","?","?");
mysql_select_db("?");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");


$id = 'id';
$user_id = 'user_id';
$first_name = 'first_name';
$last_name = 'last_name';
$dept = 'dept';

$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

?>
```

I am trying to pull all 4 rows by id to be auto generated by a single table script.

[image: http://imgur.com/bzkItsK]

Answer (score 1):

you must iterate over your results.

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

will only fetch the first entry.
You have do something like this:

```
<?php while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)): ?>
  <tr>
     <th scope="row"><?php echo $rows[$user_id];?></th>
     <td><?php echo $rows[$first_name];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $rows[$last_name];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $rows[$dept];?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

EDIT:
And please do not use mysql, use mysqli instead.

Comment: Very helpful.  Worked great!  Thanks for the input so much!